# Mongodb get element from object

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection on which if I do a find().pretty gives me the following values

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("55f7a2a9247a911393333681"),
  "education": [
    "Schooling",
    "Plus 2",
    "Graduate",
    "Post Graduate"
  ],
  "identification": [

  ],
  "jobtype": [

  ],
  "actor": [

  ]
}
```

Can I just get the values under "actor" without getting the entire collection and then iterating through the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple. You can use the following query,

```
 db.collection.distinct('actor')
```